# Triple integral using spherical coordinates ($\theta$ variation)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I have to calculate the integral
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}-y^{2}}}e^{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{3/2}}dzdydx$$
using spherical coordinates. Since I did:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l} x=\rho\sin\phi\cos\theta \\ y=\rho\sin\phi\sin\theta \\ z=\rho\cos\phi\end{array}\right.$$
I got then:
$$0\leq\phi\leq\frac{\pi}{2},\quad0\leq\theta\leq\pi,\quad0\leq\rho\leq1$$
Well, I calculated the integral and I got
$$\frac{\pi}{3}(e-1)$$
as answer. But in the book, the correct answer is
$$\frac{2\pi}{3}(e-1)$$
And I just got this answer when I change the variation of $\theta$: not from $0$ to $\pi$, but
$$-\pi\leq\theta\leq\pi$$
For me, $0\leq\theta\leq\pi$ is the right variation of $\theta$. Why am I wrong?

Comment: I obtained the same $\frac{\pi}{3}(e-1) \approx 1.79938$ as your original result. Either (1) there's a human error in the book, or (2) there's an error in how you setup the integral. Are you sure the region is over a quarter of a sphere and not a hemisphere? Just saying.

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: Your textbook probably miscalculated this.